# How to get out of this token authenticator Hilt dependency cycle?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I have a function that returns an API, which needs an OkHttpClient instance

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AuthNetworkModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAuthRetrofitService (@AuthQualifier okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): IQuipsAuth{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("${Config.BASE_URL}/")
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                .build().create(IQuipsAuth::class.java)
    }
```

And I also have a function that returns an OkHttpClient that needs an API instance for the authenticator, what do I do?

```
    @Provides
    @AuthQualifier
    fun provideOkHttpClient (application: Application,  iQuipsAuth: IQuipsAuth): OkHttpClient {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(object : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
            override fun log(message: String) {
                Log.d("HttpLoggingInterceptor", message)
            }
        }).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS)

        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .hostnameVerifier { _: String?, _: SSLSession? -> true }
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .addInterceptor(AccessTokenInterceptor(application, iQuipsAuth))
                .authenticator(AccessTokenAuthenticator(application, iQuipsAuth))
                .build()

    }
}
```

I am trying to recreate this same Koin code in Hilt:

```
single {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(object : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
            override fun log(message: String) {
                Log.d("HttpLoggingInterceptor", message)
            }
        }).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .hostnameVerifier { _: String?, _: SSLSession? -> true }
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()


        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("${Config.baseUrl}/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(get()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()

        retrofit.create(IQuipsAuth::class.java)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can workaround dependency cycles using `dagger.Lazy<T>`.

```
fun provideOkHttpClient (application: Application, iQuipsAuth: Lazy<IQuipsAuth>): OkHttpClient {
    // ...

            .addInterceptor(AccessTokenInterceptor(application, iQuipsAuth)) // pass lazy
            .authenticator(AccessTokenAuthenticator(application, iQuipsAuth)) // pass lazy

    // ...
}
```

Then invoke `lazy.get()` when the client is actually used.

Please note that this would be more self-evident if the `AccessTokenInterceptor` and `AccessTokenAuthenticator` were both provided to Dagger using `@Inject constructor`, and provided to this `@Provides` method as arguments of the method.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you want two different `OkHttpClient`s. One that `IQuipsAuth` depends on which does not use `AccessTokenInterceptor` or `AccessTokenAuthenticator` (do you really want those when talking to the Auth service directly?). Another `OkHttpClient` would be for your other services that uses `IQuipsAuth` for authentication.

You can distinguish between two instances of the same type using qualifiers. Here's a snippet on using qualifiers with hilt: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#multiple-bindings

Comment: The issue isn't qualifiers, the issue is the dependency cycles being created because the OkHttpClient and Api provider functions are dependent on each other due to authentication as is written here

.addInterceptor(AccessTokenInterceptor(application, iQuipsAuth))
.authenticator(AccessTokenAuthenticator(application, iQuipsAuth))

Comment: You really want calls on IQuipsAuth to invoke AccessTokenInterceptor and AccessTokenAuthenticator?

Comment: I am trying to migrate from Koin and RXJava to Coroutines and Hilt and rewrite this same code here in Hilt (I will edit question)